# Использование функции relationship() в SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

Объясните, для чего в **SQLAlchemy** использовать функцию *relationship()* при создании классов объектов, связываемых с таблицами БД,если внешние ключи можно указывать при создании классов-таблиц используя функцию *ForeignKey()* при определении столбца?
Или *relationship()* имеет смысл при использовании декларативной модели, когда для таблицы и связанного с ней объекта определяется один класс?

Укажите примеры, где показано как используется класс, имеющий поля, определенные через *relationship()*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Пример от автора [pycon2013 zzzeek](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/pycon2013_student_package/src/a5b84d0659cbf1df11766fbbdc215dbe32be8044/04_orm.py?at=master#cl-313)

Создаете две таблицы `User` и `Address`.

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(%r, %r)>" % (
                self.name, self.fullname
            )

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_address = Column(String, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

    user = relationship("User", backref="addresses")
```

При помощи `my_address_obj.user` получаем ОБЪЕКТ пользователя, а `my_user_obj.addresses` вернет список ОБЪЕКТОВ всех адресов ссылающихся на `User`. Таким образом `relationship` связывает объекты, а не просто возвращает значение `id`.

Пример из презентации:

```py
# Пока у пользователя нет "addresses"
jack = User(name='jack', fullname='Jack Bean')
jack.addresses  # Пустой список

# Добавим адресов ему
jack.addresses = [
            Address(email_address='jack@gmail.com'),
            Address(email_address='j25@yahoo.com'),
            Address(email_address='jack@hotmail.com'),
            ]
```

Т.е. вы оперируете объектами, а не id'шниками