# Запись в несколько таблиц с привязкой одной к другой с возможностью отката

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Доброго времени суток! Есть реляционная БД. Есть две таблицы A и B:

A:
id - первичный ключ
...

B:
id - первичный ключ
a_id - внешний ключ к таблице A
...

Необходимо записать данные в таблицу A, а затем выполнить запись в таблицу B. Разумеется в таблице B необходимо указать первичный ключ от только что созданной записи в таблице A. При этом нужно иметь возможность откатиться назад если например, во время записи таблицу B возникнет ошибка и запись не удастся, запись в таблице A не нужна.
Транзакция вроде не подходит так как в рамках транзакции я не могу узнать первичный ключ записи, так как запись еще не произведена, заранее генерировать какое-то число и его использовать в качестве первичного ключа для таблицы A тоже не очень подходит, хочется auto_increment ... Вопрос: какие есть пути решения для такой ситуации?

Спасибо!

Comment: Укажите вашу БД и таблицы. Я думаю вам нужно использовать транзакции для отката. А получить последний ид можно так: 
 

`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Comment: Можно создавать и использовать хранимый код? Что если записывать в таблицу А. Пробовать записывать в таблицу Б. Если запись в таблицу Б не удалась, то удалять из таблицы А? Укажите вашу БД пожалуйста, так будет проще давать советы

Comment: Вообще использую ORM Sqlalchemy, на данном этапе разработки БД - sqlite,  а вообще будет наверное MySQL

Comment: Вы мыслите запросами а не ORM. ORM более абстрактное понятие. Думаю вам поможет этот ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/336931/Использование-функции-relationship-в-sqlalchemy/418225#418225

Comment: Что такое ORM я знаю (только конечно опыта не много в использовании SQLAlchemy), именно таким образом через relationship у меня эти модели связаны. Разумеется в конечном счете мне требуется решение средствами ORM, но в первую очередь хотелось бы узнать как подобное решается без ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В SQLAlchemy в результате выполнения INSERT получается объект result с атрибутом [`inserted_primary_key`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.inserted_primary_key).

Вот он в туториале: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/tutorial.html#executing

В общем случае ответ зависит от API и базы, которую вы используете. Например [тут пишут про `INSERT INTO .. RETURNING id`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2188862/1026) в Oracle/Postgres, который работает как SELECT, возвращающий искомый ID. В SQLite есть функция `last_insert_rowid`, которую можно вызвать сразу после вставки (при условии, что соединение используется только вами). И т.д.